# Delete the last word of a line in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, sh

I'm looking for how to delete the last word of a line in shell ! 
I use sed but I only found the way how delete the lase word of every line, but not a specify line.
For exemple: I have a file test.db

```
key1 value1
key2 value2
key3 value3
```

And I just want to delete value3

```
sed -i s/'\w*$'// test.db
```

This line just delete the last word of every line !

Comment: How do you want to specify the line to delete the last word from?

Comment: jus provide number of line to your s, for example for the first line it would be: sed -i 1s/'\w*$'// test.db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to delete the last word only off of the last line, then you can use:

```
sed -i '$s/\w*$//' test.db
```

If you want to delete the last word from the line for `key3`:

```
sed -i '/key3/s/\w*$//' test.db
```

Comment: Why use double quotes to surround your sed command which have side effects when using the shell i.e `\$`. Single quotes would make the command much clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
sed -i '1{s/[^ ]\+\s*$//}' file test.db
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an `awk` to remove last field:

```
echo "one two three" | awk '{$NF="";sub(/[ \t]+$/,"")}1'
one two
```

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the last word of your line

since you are targeting the line `key3 value3`

```
  sed -i '/key3 value3/s/\S*$//' test.db
```

where \S is represents a digit that is not a space or whitespace.

**Deleting the last word of a particular line (General rule)**

```
   sed -i '/line pattern/s/\S*$//' test.db
```

line pattern represents a pattern that is found on the line that you want to target

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '$s/(\s*)\S+(\s*)$/\1\2/' file
```

this removes the last non-space token from the last line (keeping any surrounding white space).

To remove surrounding white space as well use:

```
sed -r '$s/\s*\S+\s*$//' file
```